# \bigl[ looks like \bigl\lfloor

Tags: support, mathjax

As the title says, when I use the command \bigl[, the result looks like the result corresponding to \bigl\lfloor. Compare: $\bigl[$ vs $\bigl\lfloor$. However after zooming a little ("Ctrl" + "+" on my Foxy browser) the result looks correct. I work at a 1920x1080, 22'' screen, so this is hardly a problem related to my screen. Perhaps a browser problem? I doubt, too.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's your browser/version/OS?

Comment: @RahulNarain Firefox/latest version/Windows 7.

Comment: $\bigl[$ vs $\bigl\lfloor$. I have the same bug (in Windows 7 SP1 and Google Chrome)

Comment: Damn it! this indeed has to do with the browser: I just tried with Internet Explorer and it works perfectly. Oh precious Firefox, you have disappointed me.

Comment: What happens if you change the render method?  (If you right-click some math you bring up the "Contextual Menu" $\Rightarrow$ Math Settings $\Rightarrow$ Math Renderer.)  When I'm using HTML-CSS I get this `\bigl[` vs `\bigl\lfloor` issue; but it looks fine under SVG.

Comment: It is not _just_ a browser issue. It has to do with how Firefox/Chrome interacts with Windows 7. Firefox on Debian shows the symbols just fine.

Comment: @WillieWong: Firefox on Debian?

Comment: @Thomas: okay, Iceweasel, but the codebase is largely the same, and drawing the distinction will just confuse other users. Just tried a WebKit-based browser on Debian, it also looks fine.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does turning off antialias help? Follow the steps outlined [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/942292). See also http://superuser.com/questions/453967/mozilla-firefox-anti-aliasing-different-on-different-systems I'm not saying that this is the problem, but if the top tick in `[` is missing, but is fixed when zoomed in, this is one of the things that I can think of.

Comment: The latest versions of Chrome and Firefox work fine on Fedora. I could also test Firefox on DragonFly BSD and Mint, but I suspect the results would be the same (and nobody uses BSD anyway).

Comment: Changing the math renderer to MathML as per Arthur Fischer's comment fixed it for me on Chrome with Windows 7. Now to go see what other problems have been created by the change. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this myself. But since this is very much a browser/operating system font rendering issue, I don't see anything that can be done about that beyond the workarounds suggested in the question's comments. I wish I could say something else.